# Solving C# Collection Mismatch

Tags: c#, linq, loops, foreach, linq-to-xml

I have two collections - one contains the product title - the second contains the shipping information.  The way I retrieve this information guarantees that each position in each collection go together, i.e. position [0] in collection 1 goes with position[0] in collection 2.  However, whenever the same customer orders two or more different items this is no longer true - it creates a mismatch in my collection.

In the example below the same customer, *dave lain*, orders two different items, filling two different potions in my 'b' collection, but he will only fill one position in my 'a' collection.  When I go to iterate both collections - they won't match up correctly and the wrong person will be credited with the wrong order.

XML File of product titles COLLECTION 'b':

```
<ListOrderItems>
    <OrderItem>
        <Title>ItemfromCustomer1</Title>
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderItem>
        <Title>ItemfromCustomer1</Title>
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderItem>
        <Title>ItemfromCustomer2</Title>
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderItem>
        <Title>ItemfromCustomer3</Title>
    </OrderItem>
</ListOrderItems>
```

Shipping Information COLLECTION 'a':

```
<ListOrdersResult>
    <Orders>
        <Order>
            <Name>dave lain</Name>
            <AddressLine1>630232 JEKASS RD</AddressLine1>
            <City>PARIS</City>
            <StateOrRegion>TX</StateOrRegion>
            <PostalCode>3281\8-5454</PostalCode>
            <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
            <Phone>407745186</Phone
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <Name>JOE SCHMO</Name>
            <AddressLine1>635232 CHERRY RD</AddressLine1>
            <City>PARIS</City>
            <StateOrRegion>TX</StateOrRegion>
            <PostalCode>876458</PostalCode>
            <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
            <Phone>5425546574</Phone                  
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <Name>RAY CHARLES</Name>
            <AddressLine1>6384 RED DR</AddressLine1>
            <City>MIAMI</City>
            <StateOrRegion>FL</StateOrRegion>
            <PostalCode>78457</PostalCode>
            <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
            <Phone>5478975487</Phone                  
        </Order>
    </Orders>
</ListOrdersResult>
```

My `foreach` loop uses the zip method to iterate through both collections in parallel, however when it gets to the double order, everything becomes off.

```
foreach (var address in addresses.Zip(products, (a, b) => new {a, b}))
{    
    if (string.Equals(address.b.Title, denatAlcohol, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        //execute code if product title is a match
    }

    if (string.Equals(address.b.Title, sodiumChlorate, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        //execute code if product title is a match
    }
    if (string.Equals(address.b.Title, semiNitric, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        //execute code if product title is a match
    }
    if (string.Equals(address.b.Title, leserNitric, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        //execute code if product title is a match
    }
    if (stringArray.Any(address.b.Title.Contains))
    {
        //execute code if product title is a match                        
    }
    if (address.b.Title.Equals(isopropyl))
    {
        //execute code if product title is a match           
    }
    if (address.b.Title.Equals(hazNitric))
    {
        //execute code if product title is matchg
    }     
    if (address.a.AddressLine2 != null)
    {
        //execute code with info in collection a for shipping address info
    }
    else
    {
        //execute code with info in collection a for shipping address info
    }
}
```

Comment: "everything becomes off"  What exactly do you mean by this? Furthermore could you please just post those code-parts that are relevant for the problem, not all your data and source-code?

Comment: @HimBromBeere everything becomes off meaning for instance the customer name in position [2] of collection 'a' is no longer the correct match for the product he/she ordered for position [2] in collection 'b'.  All product name - shipping information becomes disordered by one position in the collection.

Comment: @dannytaki - Could you please take a look at your sample data/code and compare to your description as it doesn't make sense together? There are properties in your code that aren't in your data. Your example "dave lain" shows no order items whatsoever. Please fix your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your example does not provide any info of some sort of keys that enforce the relationship between `Order` elements and `OrderItem` elements I will assume the `Title` is the semantic key.

The [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) method

> combines elements until it reaches the end of one of the sequences.

As it happens with your example,

> [...] if one sequence has three elements and the other one has four, the result sequence has only three elements.

So, what actually happens is that `Zip` method on the second step associates `OrderItem` *ItemFromCustomer1* with the second `Order` element from the sequence *JOE SCHMO*.

What you need to do is to group the `OrderItem`s and then flatten the collection like this:

```
addresses.Descendants("Order")
    .Zip(orders.Descendants("OrderItem")
                .GroupBy(e=>e.Element("Title").Value), 
            (a, o) => new{a,o})
    .SelectMany(tuple => tuple.o.Select(x => new{tuple.a, o = x}));
```

This is the result in LINQPad:
[image: Query results.]

However, keep in mind that **this is not the proper way to do it!**
You need to define a relationship between `Order` elements and `OrderItem` elements enforced by some sort of a foreign key so that you can perform a proper [`Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.join(v=vs.100).aspx) on those collections without ordering concerns; something like this:

```
addresses.Descendants("Order")
    .Join(orders.Descendants("OrderItem"),
        order => order.Element("Id").Value,
        orderItem => orderItem.Element("OrderId").Value,
        (order, orderItem) => new{order, orderItem});
```